# How do I override a translation in Liferay?

Tags: java, jar, build, liferay

I need to change some of Liferay's built in messages and translations that I've found packaged within portal-impl.jar

When I extracted the files, changed them and rebuilt the jar, Liferay stopped working - I only changed a value in a language bundle. No portlets were deployed on server startup and hot deploy stopped working too. Is this due to a signed jar that now isn't properly signed any more? What other alternatives do I have to override my translation?

(edited - the initial headline and intro to the question where about the assumption that the jar's digital signature had something to do with it. The answer and comments suggest different)

Comment: The signature is not for the JAR file as a whole, but a list of checksums for individual files. If you don't change any of the signed files, you should be able to put it together again. Was that language bundle file part of the signature?

Comment: I'm not even sure if that jar was signed. It's just something I thought could have been the reason why it stopped working. Thanks for clearing it up

Comment: You can check the MANIFEST of your original file if it was signed.

Comment: Which line should I look at?

Comment: There should be something in META-INF called *.SF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and it stopped working after I rebuilt it even though I only changed a
>   value in a language bundle.

is not a language-hook designed for this purpose. You can change the value of any property within the portal with a language-hook.

Its not recommended to change the `portal-impl.jar`, i think you already know that. Though it should still work, since liferay's patches re-build it after changing the contents.

Comment: I wanted to change the default session timeout message. I created a hook of the Language.properties file and set a new value for warning-your-session-has-expired but didn't work. The only was I could get it to work is to change the above jar. I eventually did it editing it with emacs so I didn't have to rebuild it

Comment: Well i changed the exact same thing without any issues in 6.0, 6.1 and 6.2 with a language-hook

Comment: I just managed to get the hook working. I needed a language file called Language_en_GB.properties as I'm based in the UK. You would think Language_en.properties will be good enough but apparently not. Thanks for input

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you. And by the way Language_en is default for en_US and not en_GB. If you would have been more clearer in your question that would have been the answer :-). Cheers!